# Shouldn't the infinite range of gravity be seen as troubling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

I've heard a lot of talk that infinities emerging in physics equations usually indicate that a mistake has been made somewhere and given that gravity seems to be a perennial mystery shouldn't there be some effort to remove the infinity regarding gravity's seemingly unrealistic range? I can't seem to reconcile the idea that a finite mass would produce a force that would act over an infinite distance unless that force were to act over an infinite amount of time. Isn't there something somewhere about one infinity implying another infinity? Shouldn't this infinity, like other infinities, be subject to renormalization (if that's the correct term)?

Comment: This is silly.  The OP is finish for an opinion.  It *could* become a good question but right now I'm voting to close.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean?

Comment: I've deleted most of the comments, some of which were obsolete, some of which appeared to be answering the question, some of which were [somewhat inappropriate for this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/conduct), and some of which were replies to other deleted comments.

Comment: I don't see why this question has gathered downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinities such as infinite space and infinite-ranged forces have not been a problem in physics. The problematic infinities are things like infinite energy density (which causes infinite spacetime curvature and makes it impossible to integrate the equations of motion through a singularity) and non-renormalizable quantum corrections (where infinities arise when calculating observable quantities and cannot be buried by making infinite adjustments to the “bare” quantities such as mass and charge that appear in the Langtangian to get their actual finite measured values).

An infinite range for gravity does not create problems, just like an infinite range for electromagnetism does not create problems. In quantum electrodynamics, the infinite range of electromagnetism is a consequence of the masslessness of the photon. It is actually when the photon has mass, giving the range of the force an exponential cutoff, that problems arise! The theory becomes non-renormalizable, so calculations of observable quantities become infinite, and charge conservation is no longer assured.

So, ironically, in QED one harmless infinity, namely an infinite range due to a massless photon, is what *prevents* many harmful infinities that would otherwise render the theory useless.

In the eventual theory of quantum gravity, the graviton is very likely to be exactly massless, and the gravitational force of infinite range, for a similar reason. Without it, the theory probably won’t be renormalizable.

Answer (score -2):

Don’t get encouraged. The question is ok, the people react only in a specific way, which shows, that you run into a sacrilege.

The question is reasonable. Firstly, a infinite range of the power of a field needs infinite energy in every point of the field. Secondly, the quantization of a field is impossible for infinite fields, because the quanta of such fields should be infinite small and this is a contradiction by itself.

Furthermore the answers show the common concept of the interaction of electric and magnetic fields via photons.  And yes, photons are traveling to infinity (or in “circles” if suppose that the universe is closed), as long as they not hit a particle. But does that mean, that the intermediate the electric fields of two electrons or the magnetic field of the first electron and the electric field of the second electron? If photons are responsible for both fields, why the electric field not interacts with the magnetic field? Instead of working on this questions, virtual photons were introduced to explain interactions. With the virtual photons help something is explained, what not happens in reality.

How, for symmetry, two electrons should interact at the same time exchanging photons? Intermediated by other photons in between the distance between them? Such a concept comes close to the definition, of what fields are. But as long as the constituents of electric fields, magnetic fields and photons is not under interest of science, no progress will be.

Comment: “A infinite range of the power of a field needs infinite energy in every point of the field.” No, it doesn’t. The energy density of an electromagnetic field is $(\mathbf{E}^2+\mathbf{B}^2)/8\pi$. This is not infinite anywhere unless the field itself is infinite somewhere.

Comment: “The quantization of a field is impossible for infinite fields.” No, it isn’t. Physicists quantized the infinite-range EM field to produce QED. It makes predictions accurate to one part in a trillion and has never been falsified by any observation.